# Running a powershell command inside cmd script and replacing string content

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying to run a powershell command inside cmd script for replacing a text file content

```
set file="C:\myfile.txt"

powershell -command "(Get-Content %file%) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "Latest", "FOO" } | Set-Content %file%"
```

I am getting the following error:

> You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the
>   '-replace' operator.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT** (not sure if relevant to the answer...)

The file content is

```
\\10.10.10.10\Shared\Latest
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not nesting strings correctly

```
powershell -command "(Get-Content %file%) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "Latest", "FOO" } | Set-Content %file%"
                    ^----------------------------------------------------^
               string start                                        string end
```

Use single quotes:

```
powershell -command "(Get-Content %file%) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'Latest', 'FOO' } | Set-Content %file%"
```

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers it seems to work as `%file%` - I guess the command prompt does the substitution for that before calling powershell.exe.